Помогите найти ошибку в запросе select into
SELECT st.[№зач_книжки], [Фамилия], [Имя], [Отчество],
  [Наименование], [НомерГруппы], [НаименованиеДисциплины], 
  [Стипендия], [Оценка] 
FROM [Дисциплины] as d, [Студент] as st, 
  [Факультеты] as f, [Экзамен] as ex  
INTO ttt
WHERE st.[КодФакультета]=f.[КодФакультета]
  and st.[№зач_книжки]=ex.[№зач_книжки]
  and ex.[КодДисциплины]=d.[КодДисциплины]
ORDER BY [Фамилия], [Имя], [Отчество];

Этот запрос выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку во фразе FROM
Потратил уже 2 часа

Как только убираю into ttt - работает

Что такое ваше ttt? Это должен быть тип record или в конструкции into должны быть переменные под все выбранные поля и запрос должен возвращать 1 строку.

Микрософт говорит что порядок не правильный,
SELECT field1[, field2[, ...]]
INTO newtable [IN externaldatabase] 
FROM source

и сортировку, предполагаю, нужно убрать.

Спасибо, фраза INTO действительно не на месте.
Ей место после списка полей
